# prefers-color-scheme activated whether dark mode is activated or not

Tags: css, darkmode

I'm using the following CSS to invert an image under dark mode on my site:

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

    #main-logo img {filter: invert(1);}

}
```

It works for dark mode but it's activated on light mode as well. I'm not sure how I can modify this to make it work - it seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

you need javascript `toggle` method for this

```js
function darkMode() {
  const element = document.getElementById("main-logo");
  element.classList.toggle("darkmode");
}
```

when you run this function it will change to darkmode and when you run it again, it will change to default

```css
.darkmode{
  //your css dark mode code
}
```

Comment: is this what you want? @TonyFriz

Comment: Sort of, is there a way to do it with the code I originally posted? Using @media?